# Complex Numbers - Complex Exponentials problem

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve this problem: $(a - e^{ix}))(a - e^{-ix})$ express as quadratic with all real coefficients. x(angle) ∈ R

Current working out:

$a^2 - ae^{-ix} - ae^{ix} + e^{ix}e^{-ix}$

$a^2 - ae^{-ix} - ae^{ix} + e^{i0}$

$a^2 - ae^{-ix} - ae^{ix} + 1$

I'm not sure where to go from here, could someone kindly help!

Comment: The answer is $a^{2}-2a \cos x +1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(a-e^{it})(a-e^{-it})= a^2-a(e^{it}+e^{-it})+1=a^2-2a\cos t+1$$
Every thing is real in the last quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) of $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$ to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a^2 - ae^{-i\theta} - ae^{i\theta} + 1 & = a^2 - a(\cos(-\theta) + i\sin(-\theta)) - a(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)) + 1 \\
& = a^2 - a(\cos(\theta) - i\sin(\theta)) - a(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)) + 1 \\
& = a^2 - 2a\cos(\theta) + 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This is now a quadratic equation in $a$ with all real coefficients.